Which episode of "Daybreak" features this bizarre zombie scene?
I'm trying to locate a specific scene from the Netflix series Daybreak (2019). The scene features a female zombie with green eyes and black hair pulling doll heads (possibly Barbie dolls) out of her body, likely from her stomach.
I've checked episodes 6 and 7, but it's not there. Can anyone help identify which episode this scene appears in, or provide any additional details about it? If you've seen this scene, please share any information you remember about the context or surrounding events.

Probably S1E2: Mrs. Crumble reaches into her own mouth and pulls out a doll head. She then lets Josh rummage around for his keys.



